# verifying bitcoin core version 22.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, verification

I'm trying to verify the bitcoin core version 22.0 but when I verified it seems all the signatures are bad (I downloaded SHA256SUMS.asc and SHA256SUMS files from https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/).

Comment: Can you share the result of the verification? Can you explain what did you do to verify so we can help you?

Comment: never mind IDK why but the problem have solved